# Intranet Winforms application - How to design login and role based access

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, active-directory

I have a scenario where I will be involved in windows application which is inside the office (intranet).

There is an active directory in place. The windows application contains different screens which are accessible based on the person that has logged in. I know you can get login information of a particular person from active directory. How do you design roles?

Do you have any suggestions on how this can be effetively implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(on a Windows XP) Start > Run > mmc > in the mmc Console > File > Add/Remove Snap-in > Add > Active Directory Users and Computers  > Add > Close > OK

*If you dont see Active Directory Users and Computers listed ask a SysAdmin to give you permission.*

Expand Active Directory Users and Computers > domain.com > name of main Organisation Unit > .. > .. > Users > right click on a user > Properties

In the Users Properties select the MemberOf tab and you will see how AD Groups/Roles work.

Then read this article for everything you need to know about accessing AD in c#:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#35

Please advise if its VB.Net? Also can you RDP onto the Domain Controller?

Comment: Yes sir it is VB.NET. I dont have information on RDP onto the domain controller.